# How to control rendering of images in browser for different form factors while using media query?

Tags: image, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Images for mobile form factors are also getting downloaded in the browser when i use the desktop version. Is there any way i can load those images only in mobile form factor and not in desktop as i have different images for desktop.

> **Note:**
>
> > I am building an adaptive design, not responsive. Hence it is fine
> >     only those respective images of those form factors alone gets
> >     downloaded.

Example code:

```
    1. For mobile:

    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
            div#wrapper {
                background-image: url(media-queries-iphone5.jpg);
                width: 400px;
            }

            div#header {
                background-image: url(media-queries-iphone6.jpg);
                height: 93px;
                position: relative;
            }

            div#header h1 {
                background-image: url(media-queries-iphone6s.jpg);
                font-size: 140%;
            }

            #content {
                 background-image: url(media-queries-iphone5s.jpg);
                float: none;
                width: 100%;
            }

            #navigation {
                background-image: url(media-queries-iphonese.jpg);
                float:none;
                width: auto;
            }
        }

 2. For desktop:
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        div#wrapper {
                background-image: url(media-queries-samsung.jpg);
                width: 400px;
            }

            div#header {
                background-image: url(media-queries-dell.jpg);
                height: 93px;
                position: relative;
            }

            div#header h1 {
                background-image: url(media-queries-hp.jpg);
                font-size: 140%;
            }

            #content {
                 background-image: url(media-queries-macpro.jpg);
                float: none;
                width: 100%;
            }

            #navigation {
                background-image: url(media-queries-mac.jpg);
                float:none;
                width: auto;
            }
}
```

Comment: FYI, `*-device-width / *-device-height` has been deprecated and you should use `*-width / *-height` instead.

Comment: If the rule of the media query is meet, in this case to a certain width, it does not matter whether that is a mobile or desktop. At what point does the desktop still down load images?